# Why did curved forks disappear?

Tags: fork, framebuilding, history

Forks on historical bikes are often curved forward in a smooth curve, sometimes called a "French bend". This is sometimes claimed to add a small amount of compliance and comfort. It effectively increases the rake and trail without slackening the head angle. Why did the industry stop making forks like that?

[image]

Current forks (except for retro designs) are mostly straight, having a sharp "bend" at the crown, i.e. steerer tube and fork legs usually don't form one straight line. The angle is small though, so hard to see on most bikes.

[image]

Comment: They're still pretty common on steel bikes/forks, and surely you don't consider all steel bikes "retro"?

Comment: Increasing fork offset, whether by curved fork legs or angled ones, reduces trail, not increases it.

Comment: If you make a straight line between axle and crown on your steel bike photo, the fork would look the same as the Willier carbon bike in your second photo. So your eye is tricking you: the rake is probably identical

Comment: Reading just the title in the Hot Network Questions, I was thinking "What? I just used a curved fork today, they certainly didn't disappear". Then I noticed this is about bicycles.

Comment: I feel the premise of the question is wrong, at least as far as Eastern European bike shops are concerned. My local bike shop sells a myriad of cheap stainless steel city bikes with curved forks. Few of them are intentionally going for a "retro" look.

Comment: @undercat I can say the same for the Netherlands. Curved forks are, in my experience, still the norm for normal city bikes.

Comment: @Noise I think that makes the question a bit more interesting—if the two designs accomplish the same thing from a frame geometry perspective, we can focus on the nuances a little more.

Comment: My bicycle is a mixed of Aluminium alloy frame and Steel fork, mind you the French curve is not as pronounce as stock photo, and the curve on mine starts at a higher point.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The main reason is the materials used.
Basically, on all bikes with bent forks the bent forks are made of steel. Steel has been mostly replaced by carbon and aluminium.

While steel is heavier, it is not prone to fatigue when bending within its fatigue limit, making it possible to use thinner tubes with more flex and allowing the bend in the fork to work like a basic shock absorber.

Aluminium has no fatigue limit, thus it needs to be stiff enough or it will eventually break, making it not suitable for comfortable flexing forks. A big curved bend puts more stress on the material than a small sharp bend at the crown.

Carbon has properties which are very different to metals. Carbon parts  are not just defined by the shape of the object, but also by the layup of carbon fibers, making it possible to get shock absorbing characteristics without needing a bend to work as spring, just by engineering the right layup of fibers.

That's the why many aluminium bikes use carbon forks.

There are other big reasons why bent forks are less common on modern bikes. You could say, why use an expensive carbon fork on your aluminium bike, if a cheap steel fork would be as comfortable?

Looks!

A thin tubed round bend steel fork just doesn't look right on a thick edgy carbon or aluminium frame. Also thin steel tubes aren't as aerodynamic as the optimized shapes you can make with carbon or hydroformed aluminium.

Comment: There are some interesting carbon forks that take things a step further, by designing a more complex bent section, but I've only ever seen them on the road and can't track them down online

Comment: @ChrisH you probably think of Lauf suspension forks from Iceland. I thought about adding them as an example of exotic carbon forks. But i think this would be out of scope.

Comment: @airace3 I looked at the current Lauf designs and it wasn't them. What I saw looked like a single piece of carbon with either an S bend or a coil at the bottom. I can remember more about the cafe I saw it at than the bike, which says a lot about my priorities

Comment: @ChrisH Are you perhaps thinking about the Specialized Zertz system?

Comment: How much shock absorption (as opposed to buzz-absorption) can you realistically get from carbon layup design? Without the bent sections alluded to by @ChrisH, it doesn’t seem likely that the fork ends are going to move much with a straight fork (because the wheel forces under expected riding are going to be directed significantly along the fork, rather than transverse to it, and so interact with the material stiffness not the structural stiffness).

Comment: Pinarello has several different bent backward or S-shaped fork shapes. I guess it tells something that they still haven’t found the optimal design.

Comment: @RLH I think that's what the bends are for - so the force does get dealt with by structure. Those forks are all about road (or gravel) buzz and not big hits - but so is any compliance in curved steel forks

Comment: @ojs I suspect that's true, especially taking into account performance vs cost, though there's also margin for styling. The pinarello forks I've seen online are closer but look less striking than the ones I saw IRL

Comment: @MaplePanda what I recall was lower down the fork than the zertz pictures I've seen.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree that's what the bends are for. I was questioning airace3's assertion that the layup structure can meaningfully provide shock absorption.

Comment: @RLH ah, I see, too much discussion for me to follow, all while I wasn't looking

Comment: @RLH due to steering angle and rake the force isn't in direction of the fork regardless if it is straight or curved. There is a perpendicular component to the force. It is thus subject to a bending moment.

Answer (score 17):

Frames and forks were made of tubes that are brazed into lugs. Lugs are cast standard parts. Frames are sized by using tubes of the correct length. The respecive production processes makes lugs stiff and tubes flexible.

The front axle is offset roughly 40 mm from the axis of the steerer tube. This offset is named [rake](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/73391/how-does-fork-offset-affect-bike-handling). Rake determines steering characteristics.

Most curved forks are made from steel and consist of a straight steerer tube, a crown lug, and two tapered tubes as fork members.

In the context of above aspects there are a number of good reasons to have curved members:

- by curving the fork members any rake can be set with a straight crown
- curving tubes was easy for metal workers of the old
- crown lugs are standard parts, different rake for different steerer angles would necessitate a large number of crowns; this would drive costs of crowns up considerably
- a stiff part that also joins members by brazing is not a good spot to take torsional moments
- curved forks lived on because of tradition for a while after the technological necessities changed

Why are such forks gone?
Simply put. If no external constraints force you to curve something, keep it straight.

- Stress in a straight beam is smaller than in a curved beam ([cf. curved beams](https://roymech.org/Useful_Tables/Beams/Curved_beams.html)).
- Better shock damping: a long stretch of material bending a bit is better than a short section bending a lot. (For the same reason it is better to have long leaf springs in a truck's suspension than short ones.)
- Modern manufacturing and quality control of curved parts is more expensive.
- Fashion changed and there is not much demand for curved forks for aesthetic reasons alone.

Answer (score 16):

A big part of the change from curved to straight forks is the engineering requirements for disc brakes.

Curved forks provide structural flexibility, in that forces applied to the tire become transverse (or almost transverse) forces on the fork blade, allowing it to bend and absorb shocks.

Curved forks work best with rim brakes, because the brake forces are applied at the crown or the crown end of the fork blades, and the blades can be engineered for shock absorption.

With disc brakes, the blades need to be able to support a torque load at the end of the fork blade, and so need to be made stiffer, which puts a ceiling on the shock absorption that could be achieved by structural flexibility.

Once structural flexibility is no longer on offer, the various aesthetic and material concerns raised in the other answers start to drive fork design.

Some discussion on this topic:
https://www.renehersecycles.com/myth-9-fork-blades-dont-flex/

Comment: My most curved forks happen to be with disc brakes (steel tourer from 2017). My MTB (2017 aluminium, disc brakes) has straight forks with the dropouts forward of the leg centre, as does a steel BSO (V brakes). My 2010 hybrid (Al, v brakes) has the dropouts centred under the fork legs. So the correlation certainly isn't perfect

Comment: Agreed   https://www.rodbikes.com/articles/graphics/bentfork1.gif  there's a traditional steel fork that had disk caliper tabs welded on with no internal reinforcing added.   Thin and petite fork tines couldn't handle the new sideways loads.

Comment: I'm sure the mass change to straight forks happened much earlier than when disc brakes became common (at least on road bikes or non-suspension forks in general).

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what was discussed in other answers, there is one significant detail: flat mount disc brakes. The flat mount brakes that are almost universal on road bikes require a flat mounting point right where the curve used to be. Building the flat mounting surface into a curved fork blade would be more complicated than straight one and not look as clean, and since the curve isn't necessary for function, straight blades won.

As far as I remember, curved carbon forks were more common than straight ones until disc brakes became common. Straight ones existed even before carbon fiber, but they were considered to be exotic and just for the looks.

Comment: Specifically flat mount, as you say at the top. Post mount are fine on curved forks. But discs became common on performance road bikes about the time flat mount took off; they've been around longer on endurance bikes

Comment: @ChrisH *But discs became common on performance road bikes about the time flat mount took off; they've been around longer on endurance bikes*  Likely because UCI dragged its feet on approving disc brakes for races.  IIRC UCI only approved disc brakes for road racing in 2018 or so.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I reckon that's right. I'm not all that interested in racing (watching or taking part, though I'd try time trialling) so wasn't sure enough of the timing to say so

Comment: Flatmount requires such a small area that I want to call this answer out as potential hogwash:  an lS mount requires more flat space to mount easily. Any steel frame rear flatmount demonstrates the possibility of incorporating one into a fork but without any clear benefits: postmount is available still for road.

Comment: @Noise are rear triangles usually curved?

Answer (score 2):

My 1979 Sekai 4000 has a nice French bend in the fork. I ride several bikes, one with a carbon fork and 35 mm tires, and this bike with its 25 mm tires soaks up the bumps better. I can see it working. On a section of boardwalk that rattles everything, me included, that fork is springing up and down and takes the rattle out better than any of my other bikes. Old tech but it sure works well! Not implying we all go back to the 70s but sometimes as the tech moves forward, the benefits of the old tech are lost.

[image]

Comment: Nice bike!  However, the question is specifically around why the curved fork went away.  Your carbon-fork bike is probably much straighter, but its also made of carbon fibre not steel.   So is the reason for straighter forks a consequence of the material used to make them ?

Answer (score -2):

When I was a kid in the '60s and early seventies we used to cut the front forks off an old bike and slip them onto the end of our bike's forks and make a chopper. It was very cool but very dangerous so around 1980 they started making front forks that couldn't be attached to one another.
I think that is the answer you are looking for. Nothing complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Your answer does not answer the question why curved forks disappeared. It wasn't so that we couldn't make a chopper.